# Как сделать текст поверх адаптивного фона?

Tags: html, css

Пример:

```css
.header__mid {
  max-width: 635px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #ccc;
}

.header__title {
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 635px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header__subtitle {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  max-width: 445px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.header__link {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.header__line {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 344px;
  height: 720px;
  background: rgba(0, 91, 193, 0.6);
  left: -150px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__mid">
  <h1 class="header__title">Светотехническое оборудование в Петербурге</h1>
  <div class="header__subtitle">Продажа, аренда светотехнического оборудования. Оформление официальных мероприятий под ключ.</div>
  <a class="header__link" href="#">ПЕРЕЙТИ</a>
  <h5 class="header__line"></h5>
</div>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDaZV.jpg
```

Comment: наверное перекрыть z-index

Comment: не помогает, указал, но ничего особо не дало

Comment: Добавьте так же блокам с текстом ```position: relative```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.header__title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* other styles */
}

.header__subtitle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  /* other styles */
}
```